# How to prepare SimplePie_Item's get_date() for l10n?

Tags: localization, simplepie, l10n

I'm trying to improve the localization of the Bones theme. On the admin side it provides an RSS widget which uses the following code:

```
<?php
   echo $item->get_date('j F Y @ g:i a');
?>
```

This uses SimplePie, [here's the doc](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_date) for the method.
Which would be the best way to make this translatable?

Answer (score 2):

Best way would probably be to use the built in Internationalization function in WordPress. This will then translate according to the language pack being used.

The "U" character to a date() call gives the unix timestamp, which is just what you need in this case, for passing to `date_i18n()`.

For example:
`echo date_i18n('j F Y @ g:i a', $item->get_date('U'));`

The months and such will be translated accordingly. If you want to add the __() wrapper around the date format string, that will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this one?

```
<?php 
    echo mysql2date(__('j F Y @ g:i a', 'bonestheme'), $item->get_date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); 
?>
```